# Is it safe to use namebench?

Tags: dns

As the title states is Google's namebench utility safe to run on my Mac and let it use Safari's web history?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Namebench uses your cached browser info and there is an option to allow your anonymized results to be uploaded to Google, which you can [turn off](http://code.google.com/p/namebench/wiki/UsingNameBench).

The bug [tracker](http://code.google.com/p/namebench/issues/list) has no bugs related to malicious activity. The Python [source](http://code.google.com/p/namebench/source/browse/#svn/trunk%253Fstate%253Dclosed) code is available for everyone to inspect.

There is no reason to suspect this application of 'un-safe' activity.

What un-safe results do you wish to avoid?

Comment: Sending any info to Google and the app possibly doing anything malicious. I know the source code is available, but I don't have the skill to vet it. Thanks.

Comment: It appears that you can prevent info going to Google, and the code looks like the public reviewers are ok with what they have found.